# Change the stacked bar chart to Stacked Percentage Bar Plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, stacked-chart

How can I change this stacked bar into a **stacked Percentage Bar Plot**  with percentage labels:

here is the code:

```
df_responses= pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eng-aomar/Security_in_practice/main/secuirtyInPractice.csv')

df_new =df_responses.iloc[:,9:21]
image_format = 'svg' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.

# initialize empty dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

# group by each column counting the size of each category values
for col in df_new:
    grped = df_new.groupby(col).size()
    grped = grped.rename(grped.index.name)
    df2 = df2.merge(grped.to_frame(), how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

# plot the merged dataframe
df2.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just calculate the percentages yourself e.g. in a new column of your dataframe as you do have the absolute values and plot this column instead.
Using `sum()` and division using dataframes you should get there quickly.

You might wanna have a look at [GeeksForGeeks post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stacked-percentage-bar-plot-in-matplotlib/) which shows how this could be done.

### EDIT

I have now gone ahead and adjusted your program so it will give the results that you want (at least the result I think you would like).
Two key functions that I used and you did not, are [`df.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`df.transpose()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html). You might wanna read on those two as they are quite helpful in many situations.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df_responses= pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eng-aomar/Security_in_practice/main/secuirtyInPractice.csv')

df_new =df_responses.iloc[:,9:21]
image_format = 'svg' # e.g .png, .svg, etc.


# initialize empty dataframe providing the columns
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_new.columns)


# loop over all columns
for col in df_new.columns:
    # counting occurences for each value can be done by value_counts()
    val_counts = df_new[col].value_counts()
    # replace nan values with 0
    val_counts.fillna(0)
    # calculate the sum of all categories
    total = val_counts.sum()
    # use value count for each category and divide it by the total count of all categories
    # and multiply by 100 to get nice percent values
    df2[col] = val_counts / total * 100

# columns and rows need to be transposed in order to get the result we want  
df2.transpose().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I read the code but I did not understand it :(

Comment: I have edited my anwser to provide a python solution to your question :) hope this will be useful